# Masking a password field within a dataset

Tags: c#

I have created a form called "User profiles" where I want to be able to update user information.  This data is simply taken from an Access table called, "DD User profiles".

I simply dragged the table (from Data Sources) onto a blank form and sure enough it has everything I need.  However, I would like to be able to mask the "Password" field and was wondering if there is an easy way to do it (I'm pretty new to C#).

Comment: Are you storing passwords in cleartext?

Comment: Please give more Information about how your store the passwords(plaintext, encrypted), and what you want to display (points, nothing, length...)

Comment: Just remove the column from the grid and the DataTable.